# I need to use VB date and read data from sql base to compare results

Tags: vb.net, date, format

I have written a unit test where I need to use general date from VB using system.

What I want is to using system data and read some from Sql base where is date format `yyyy-mm-dd`, and here is `dd.mm.yyyy`.

What I did:

```
Dim startdate As Date = Date.Now.AddMonths(-2)
Dim enddate As Date = Date.Now
```

I am trying to do assert that there is data between 2 dates, reading (from today -2 month) and read that from base, but I got error because is different format of dates.

This is under testmethod, public sub

Comment: `Dim` in C#? Are you using VB.NET?

Comment: Jes, existing unit tests..

Comment: Where do you get that error? What data type has the column containing the date? Can you show some code, please? (and why are you talking about c# if you're obviously using vb?)

Comment: I got error in results :) VB (sorry, cant change in two places), its smaldatetime column     This is Error:  System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index

Comment: Can you please show the code that throws that exception?

Comment: I made it with this:

Comment: `startdate.Date.GetDateTimeFormats()`                                                                     
`Dim dateAsString = startdate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")`